# Am I on the track for my toy language evaluator?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write an evaluator for my toy language. One thing I would like to include, are both Ints and Doubles. Here is my latest attempt:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
module Types where

import Prelude

data family Number n
data instance Number Integer = NumInt Integer deriving (Eq,Show)
-- data instance Number Double  = NumDouble Double deriving (Eq,Show)

data Expr a where
  BoolConst   :: Bool   -> Expr Bool
  NumConst    :: Number num -> Expr (Number num)

  Equals      :: Expr (Number num)  -> Expr (Number num) -> Expr Bool

class ChunkyNum a where
  equals :: a -> a -> Bool

-- more methods to be added

instance ChunkyNum (Number Integer) where
  equals a b = a == b
```

here's my eval function

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
module Eval where

import Types

eval :: Expr z -> z
eval (BoolConst b)     = b
eval (NumConst b)      = b
```

and in ghci I can do this.

```
*Main Eval Types> let five = NumConst (NumInt 5 :: Number Integer)
*Main Eval Types> let ten = NumConst (NumInt 10 :: Number Integer)
*Main Eval Types> eval five == eval ten
False
```

Now, I try to do similar in my eval function

```
eval :: Expr z -> z
eval (BoolConst b)     = b
eval (NumConst b)      = b
eval (Equals a b)      = (eval a) `equals` (eval b)
```

and then, trying to compile:

```
~/projects/git/chunky/src/Eval.hs:12:26: error:
    • Could not deduce (ChunkyNum (Number num))
        arising from a use of ‘equals’
      from the context: z ~ Bool
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   Equals :: forall num.
                             Expr (Number num) -> Expr (Number num) ->    Expr Bool,
                 in an equation for ‘eval’
        at src/Eval.hs:12:7-16
•     In the expression: (eval a) `equals` (eval b)
      In an equation for ‘eval’:
           eval (Equals a b) = (eval a) `equals` (eval b)
```

I think I am on the right track, and that I just need to provide more information to ghc. Am I, if so, what's the next step. If not, how do I go about solving this problem?

Lazersmoke, your suggestion worked, but I had to add a constraint to the Equals constructor. This was at the behest of ghc, but I wonder if it's still bad practice.

```
Equals      :: (ChunkyNum num) => Expr (Number num)  -> Expr (Number num) -> Expr Bool
```

Comment: That is correct. You can only do `Equals` on `ChunkyNum`s anyway, so that constraint makes good sense. If you are looking for design improvments, I would consider whether you actually need a data family at all. You could use a type family, or get rid of the type class entirely and operate on any `Eq`uatable or `Num`ber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GHC is telling you that it can't know that every single `Number num` will have an instance for `ChunkyNum`. You can resolve this by changing the `Number` data family to an associated data family of `ChunkyNum`:

```
class ChunkyNum a where
  data Number a :: *
  equals :: Number a -> Number a -> Bool
```

with instances like

```
instance ChunkyNum Integer where
  data Number Integer = NumInt Integer
  equals (NumInt a) (NumInt b) = a == b
```

Otherwise, you would have to write an `instance ChunkyNum (Number num) where`, which is impossible for a standalone (open) data family.

Please let me know if any of this is inapplicable to your use case.

[Further Reading](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#Instance_declarations)